# Js moments timezone

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have the following code to manipulate the time in copenhagen. I was wondering how i would be able to implement this using js moment?

```
function startTime() {
    var today=new Date();
    var i=today.getHours();
    var h = i-2;
    var m=today.getMinutes();
    var s=today.getSeconds();
    m = checkTime(m);
    s = checkTime(s);
    document.getElementById('localtime').innerHTML = h+":"+m+":"+s;
    var t = setTimeout(function(){startTime()},500);
}

function checkTime(i) {
    if (i<10) {i = "0" + i};  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
    return i;
}

<body onload="startTime()">
```

Comment: any help is appreciated, sorry for my lack of knowledge on moment.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need the timezone plugin if you want specific timezones.  Otherwise you can leave it out.  Provides .tz()

```js
function startTime() {
//local time
document.getElementById('localtime').innerHTML =
  moment().format('hh:mm:ss');

//copenhagen timezone
document.getElementById('copenhagen').innerHTML =
  moment.tz('Europe/Copenhagen').format('hh:mm:ss');
var t = setTimeout(function(){startTime()},500);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.2/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data.js"></script>
<body onload="startTime()">
  <div id="localtime"></div>
  <div id="copenhagen"></div>
</body>
```